# tar:java/xxx:Cannot create symlink to : java/xxx : Permission denied

Tags: linux, java, symbolic-link, tar, arm

OS: Chromeos 114.0.5735.205 (Official Build) (32-bit)
Kernel:Linux penguin 5.15.108
Architecture:aarch64

trying to install jdk ,

I ran :

`tar zxvf jdk-20_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz --no-same-owner`

got following errors:
[cannot create symlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5I4a.png)

saw some solutions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792980/tar-julia-xxx-cannot-create-symlink-to-xxx-operation-not-supported) regarding root filesystem but nothing on 9p type filesystem

ran `df -Th` for drive info
[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af72P.png);
ext4 is read only so nothing there to do

please let me know if there is any way to untarr the file without this symlink error..